# Ubuntu 32-bit won't install on Dell Inspiron 4000

Tags: boot, system-installation, dell, freeze

I am tuning up a laptop for a friend. The laptop originally ran Windows ME, and is about 13 years old. I recently installed Windows XP on it and it ran like a snail. I am now trying to install 32-bit Ubuntu or 32-bit Zorin OS Lite on it. XP installed fine, but Ubuntu and Zorin both become unresponsive after the option to begin the install directly (without going into the live CD). I even tried deleting the XP partition to leave it with 300 GB unpartitioned, unformatted space. Noting works, please help?

Comment: Good grief, Windows ME? Does it meet the [minimum system requirements](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements)?

Comment: Echo that.  You might need to find a lighter Linux distribution.  13 years is like 130 in computer time.

Comment: 13 years old, laptop, and with 300GB of HDD?!

Comment: @Alaa I should've realized that. It needs a RAM upgrade. I will try the install again when I get the new RAM. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I have a 2001 Toshiba Laptop with 30GB HD, and 512GB RAM, that I installed XP on for my six year old, and he was always complaining how slow it is.

What I did, is upgrade the RAM to 1GB, tried Xubuntu 13.04 first, and it was faster than XP, but then I decided to use Lubuntu, so I loaded Lubuntu 13.04 on it, and it was even a little faster that Xubuntu.  Now I can't keep him away from it.

So my suggestion, is add the extra RAM, and load Lubuntu.  Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try running Lucid Puppy off a USB drive.  This is what I usually do when trying to recover an old system, because of how lightweight it is.